# Edit button tells me that suggested edit queue is full, but it's empty, what's wrong?

Tags: support, edits

I don't review on regular basic these days, and today I've noticed that the edit button is disabled for me (everywhere, but here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/15920898)) suggesting that "suggested edit queue is full". However, my latest suggestions are all approved or rejected (couple of them).

What's going on? The tooltip is obviously wrong (there's likely no pending suggested edits at all and it can't be full since the last one is not pending). Can it be because of the couple of rejected edits? Doesn't sound reasonalble, I don't have many rejected edits, although I can't tell exact stats (the last rejection before these 2 was about 50 approved edits ago).

Comment: Catching... always.

Comment: I see 186 pending reviews right now.  That is not empty.  And close enough to the limit to see disabled UI.  Happens a lot lately, these relentless review tasks with no willingness from the company to adapt the machine to what is practical, and fair, are wearing people down.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I've noticed that the edit button is disabled for me ... suggesting that "suggested edit queue is full".

This means that the review queue for suggested edits has reached 200 suggested edits and no edits can be suggested by anyone (users with less than 2000 rep, as users with > 2000 rep do not need to have their edits reviewed so there are no edit suggestions for those users except for tag wiki edits).

You do not have access to the suggested edit review queue because you do not have the review suggested edits privilege which comes at 2000 reputation, so you cannot see how many suggested edit review tasks there are currently.

> However, my latest suggestions are all approved or rejected (couple of them).

This has no bearing on the suggested edit queue being full. You can have up to five pending edits at any given point in time, after which the edit link on posts will be disabled, but for a different reason than you are facing now.

The suggested edit queue is now down to ~170 (at the time of this writing), so you should be able to suggest an edit now.

Comment: Ah, so the "suggested edit queue" is not a queue of edits suggested by me, but rather by all users of SO?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Note: at the very least, [the Suggested Edits queue stats page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats) will show the current backlog even for logged-out users.

Answer (score 4):

> Ah, so **the "suggested edit queue" is not a queue of edits suggested by me, but rather by all users of SO [across all posts].**

Your comment deserves more spotlight as that info is key, imo. That's why I'm posting it as an answer :)

I also added another key info that I discovered -- that the suggested edit queue isn't for a single post only, it's for *all* posts across the whole page. For some reason, there can only be 200 suggested edits pending in total at any given time...

Comment: Yes, so isn't it better to the message change to "You do not have enough reputation to edit this post. (Read more)" ?